# how to extract values based upon month in xarray

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, python-xarray

I have an array of dimensions `(9131,101,191)`. The first dimension is the days from `1/1/2075` till `31/12/2099`. I want to extract all the days which are in the month of July. How can I do this in xarray? I have tried using loops and numpy but not getting the desired result. Ultimately, I want to extract all the arrays which are falling in July and find the mean.

Here is the array, its name is `initialize_c3` and its shape is `(9131,101,191)`.

```
import xarray as xr

arr_c3 = xr.DataArray(initialize_c3,
    dims=("time", "lat", "lon"),
    coords={"time": pd.date_range("2075-01-01", periods=9131, freq="D"),"lat": list(range(1, 102)),"lon": list(range(1, 192)),    
    },)
```

I have tried to groupby according to months.
`try = arr_c3.groupby(arr_c3.time.dt.month)`
After this the shape of try is `(755,1,1)` but want the dimensions of try to be `(755,101,191)`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is `xr`? is it a library or a variable ou are defining somewhere?  Please post the code that you have

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki xr has come from xarray. i am importing xarray as xr.

Comment: you should include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: Tried executing your code. It says `initialize_c3` doesn't exist. Is the code you posted a minimal reproducible example that we can execute?

Comment: Actually, the initialize_c3 is an array which cannot be uploaded here. Could you
import xarray as xr
arr_c3 = xr.DataArray(initialize_c3, dims=("time", "lat", "lon"), coords={"time": pd.date_range("2075-01-01", periods=9131, freq="D"),"lat": list(range(1, 102)),"lon": list(range(1, 192)),
},)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` to calculate the monthly climatology. Then use `sel()` to select the monthly mean for July:

```py
ds.groupby('time.month').mean().sel(month=7)
```

Another way that avoids calculating the means for the other months is to first filter all days in July:

```
ds.sel(time=(ds.time.dt.month == 7)).mean('time')
```